# Lost KDE effects after 13.10 upgrade

Tags: kubuntu, effects, kwin

After Kubuntu 13.10 upgrade, Alt+tab and desktop pager effects do not work
anymore. They are enabled in Desktop Effects.

How can I solve this issue?

It seems I have Nvidia drivers installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is provided by KDE Forums: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=118163